# Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration Cordova / BackboneJS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, backbone.js

I am trying to authenticate users in my app using Facebook Login. As mentioned in the title am using BackboneJS and the latest version of Cordova.

Target platforms are both Android and iOS. I have setup a dummy app on facebook and am trying to use it for the authentication. Also I'm using the [FacebookUser](https://github.com/fabrik42/facebook-user.js) wrapper.

But I'm constantly getting the following error -

"Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

After going through many of the solutions I could find on github / SO, I have the below settings in the app -

**Basic Settings** -
[image: Basic Settings]

---

**Advanced Settings** - 
[image: Advanced Settings]

Can someone guide me as to where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll update this in case someone also faces the same issue. What fixed my problem was -

1. Used the [Wizcorp Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)
2. Generated a key hash for the apk and updated the same
3. Also edited part of the API call to fix the issues of permissions. Apparently, if you ask for more than you are allowed to you get an error saying "Session was closed abnormally..." or something.

Hope this helps...